# Group By Child Objects

Tags: apex, custom-object, group-by

I'm facing some trouble to GROUP BY a SELECT with 2 Child Objects.
This is the following SELECT:

```
[SELECT 
    Id AtendId, BI_BR_Adabas__c, BI_BR_Adabas__r.BI_BR_Parceiro__c, BI_BR_Cliente__c, 
    BI_BR_Adabas__r.Modelo_de_Atuacao__c, BI_BR_Adabas__r.BI_BR_Parceiro__r.Name, 
    BI_BR_Adabas__r.BI_BR_Parceiro__r.BI_No_Identificador_fiscal__c, BI_BR_Escopo_de_Produto__c, 
    BI_BR_Adabas__r.BI_BR_Parceiro__r.BI_CAM_Codigo_del_cliente__c, 
    BI_BR_Adabas__r.BI_BR_Parceiro__r.Codigo_Grupo__c, BI_BR_Adabas__r.Name AdabasName
FROM 
    BI_BR_Atendimento_Comercial_e_Carteira__c 
WHERE 
    BI_BR_Cliente__c = :lCliente AND BI_BR_Adabas__r.BI_BR_Parceiro__c != null 
    AND BI_BR_Excluir__c = false AND BI_BR_Adabas__r.Modelo_de_Atuacao__c  = :lMod
GROUP BY
    BI_BR_Adabas__c, BI_BR_Cliente__c
]
```

The BI_BR_Atendimento_Comercial_e_Carteira__c Object repeats N times for the same BI_BR_Adabas__c for each BI_BR_Cliente__c and as I only need one record (all data will repeat N times because they are the same datas in multiple records)

To achieve this I'm trying to GROUP BY EACH Adabas on EACH Account(BI_BR_Cliente__c).

I'm getting the following error:

```
Line: 1, Column: 14
Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use GROUP BY, you have to include all fields that are not a summary function. If everything is identical, then include all the fields in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Hello Daniel! I'm traying your tip.
I'll edit when done! Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to drop Id from the query as that will be unique per line.

Comment: Daniel, exactly as you said, I removed the Id and used Group By for every field and it worked fine. Now I'm following with the development. Thank you!!